# Looping through jQuery collection and wrapping with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on this for a second now and the answer is eluding me.  I am sure it's simple, but it's not coming.

Essentially, I am trying to loop through a jQuery collection which is comprised of list elements and then wrap jQuery around it again in a `for` loop.  Here's my code so far:

```
for (i = 0; i < $(obj.mainNavItems).length; i += 1) {
    if ($(obj.mainNavItems)[i].has("ul")) { //wrap specific item with jQuery
        console.log("true");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am looking for a `ul` within `li` elements and acting on it if there it exists.

I am familiar with the `$.map` method, but I am not sure if it applies in this case or not.  I didn't have any luck using it.

How can I wrap jQuery around elements that I loop through??  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm confused at this "wrap around", you want to loop through `li` and do what with each?

Comment: Giving the item I am looping through access to jQuery methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('li.class:has(ul)').each(function(){ 
   // do someting
});
```

Comment: Yup, worked like a charm.  No doubt I was over thinking this one.  Will give you the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

Don't leave the jQuery selection, just filter it with `has`:

```
$(obj.mainNavItems).has("ul").each(function(index, element) {
    console.log("element " + index + " =" + element);
}
```

Comment: Gave you a +1, but I believe @nifr at the bottom is simpler and more readable.

Comment: @SethenMaleno nifr beat me to the answer, but I tried to make mine different enough to be relevant - showing how to append it to an existing query and more info on using the `each` function.  Thanks for the +1!  :-)